# LG Device Android USB Driver Issue

Tags: android, adb

I am using LG Optimus G. ADT shows that my device is offline and version is unknown as seen on the screenshot. I am sharing my device manager look also. It is installed but i think it is not properly working. I don't want to ignore that matter it is probably going to face me later.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** First ensure that the device is set up properly for USB debugging. Check that

```
- you have installed the proper driver for your phone on your PC.
- you have enabled USB debugging in Developer Settings.
```

**2.** After you have done the first step, when you connect your phone to the PC, a dialog will popup on your phone prompting you to accept the computer's RSA key. Accept it and the device will be shown as online in your IDE.

**3.** As a last resort, you can try re-starting your IDE. This will force `adb` to start properly.

Comment: That didn't work for me.I have installed the driver and enabled usb debugging as well. At the first it have already apperead a popup window and i have already accepted it. The 3rd step as well didn't help. The issue continiues.

Comment: try disconnecting and reconnecting your cable

Comment: Thanks we solved it. I did adb kill-server on cmd and start-server. That worked.